# My computer doesn't boot up

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a laptop and I formatted it and installed windows 7ultimate 64 bit version. But after started working with it I realized that there is a unallocated space of 275GB is available on my harddisk. So I went to the disk manager and I created a new partition from it.But I remember that the unallocated space was in the type of logical.Now I can't boot up windows.

Please anyone help to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use bootrec.exe**

- Set your BIOS to boot to CD
- Use your Windows 7 Disk to boot to
- Press any key when prompted.
- Select time, currency, language, keyboard when prompted
- Select 'Repair Computer'
- In the **system recovery options** select **command prompt**
- Type bootrec.exe in the command window

Use the bootrec.exe /fixmbr then bootrec.exe /fixboot options

**IF that doesn't work**

You can edit your boot.ini file on the root of your hard drive and set the arc path.

[This article gives a concise path](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/102873).  You would edit your partition and detriment one number, more than likely.

Comment: Please explain this: "You would edit your partition and detriment one number, more than likely."

Comment: If you have an ARC path in your boot.ini that does not get corrected using the first procedure you can refer to the article I included to try and edit the ARC path and set the boot drive to (0) or (1) depending on if you have a utility partition that Lenovo sets up for you.  zero if you don't, 1 if you do.  It would probably be set to 2 right now pointing at your third partition you created.